# Sorting vector of vector of doubles

Tags: c++, opencv

I have vector of previous clusters, and a vector of current clusters. A cluster has a vector of 2D Point2F, I would like to sort out those clusters ascendly based on the distance between each cluster, which is stored in distance vector, or can you suggest a better way to sort the clusters vector ?

```
 distances.resize(previousClusters.size()*currentClusters.size());
         for (int i=0; i<previousClusters.size()*currentClusters.size(); i++)
         {
             distances[i].resize(previousClusters.size()*currentClusters.size());
         }

         for (int i=0; i< previousClusters.size(); i++)
         {

             for(int j=0; j < currentClusters.size(); j++)
             {

                 distances[i][j] = cv::norm(previousClusters[i].m_Properties.m_Center - currentClusters[j].m_Properties.m_Center );
             }
         }
```

Comment: How do you want them ordered? What does it mean to compare two `vector<double>`s?

Comment: `std::sort()`. If you want more details, you'll have to give more details: explain what you want the result of sorting to be.

Comment: when is one vector of doubles larger than the other? when it has more entries? when the sum of the entries is larger? when the average of the entries is larger? When the largest entry is larger?

Comment: when it has less value the other

Comment: @Moaz: hm, but what is the value in your case? If it is a vector, how would you compare two vectors?

Comment: perhaps he means, when it has less values than the other. In other words, when it has a smaller size.

Comment: "when it has less value the other" i think there is some confusion here. A std::vector is not a vector in the mathematical sense. It is a container class which behaves similar to an array.

Comment: I would like to compare the two vectors of points, if point B is less than point B, the swap it and sort

Comment: @Philipp: in context of OpenCV, std::vector _may_ be used to represent a mathematical vector. Though it's still not clear how to compare them.

Comment: How do you decide when one point is less than another? For example, compare (1,2) and (2,1). Which is smaller?

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @kevin based on the distance between the clusters

Comment: Note, that while perfectly fine in C++11, vector of vectors does not scale well in C++03 due to the reallocations. If you can't use C++11 compiler with move semantics, a workaround is to use the [`boost::container::vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/container.html), that provides move semantics on C++03 using library trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: this answers the question as it was originally written (and as it still is written in the title). The body of the question has changed to invalidate it, but the answer might still be useful for sorting a vector of vectors.

First, you need to decide what it means for one vector to be sorted before another, and write a comparator:

```
struct compare_distance_vectors {
    bool operator()(std::vector<double> const & v1, std::vector<double> const & v2) {
        // implement your comparison here.
        // return "true" if v1 should come before v2.
    }
};
```

Then use `std::sort` to sort according to that ordering:

```
std::sort(vectors.begin(), vectors.end(), compare_distance_vectors());
```

If you want a *lexicographical* ordering (i.e. ordering by the first element, then by the second if that's equal, and so on), then you can use the default comparator (which is `std::less<value_type>`, and uses `<` to compare):

```
std::sort(vectors.begin(), vectors.end());
```

Generally, to sort a sequence of any type (such as `std::vector<cv::Point2f>`) according to any ordering, write a comparator like that to specify the ordering, and then use `std::sort` with that comparator.

Comment: I have updated my question with more clarification, I think that is not what I needed ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [std::sort](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) on the "upper" vector (the second prototype allows you to define the way the "lower" vectors should be sorted) first, and then each time your function object Comp is called, use std::sort again on each "lower" method (with the first prototype being enough this time).

This can also work for your second question.